# Illegal Invocation instantiating BS Modal

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to call a bootstrap Modal in angular via the component rather than using it's HTML attribute. I'm getting an error (i.e. illegal invocation).

Component:

```
@ViewChild('myModal') div:any;

ngAfterViewInit() {let bs = new bootstrap.Modal(this.div);}
```

HTML

```
<div class="modal-content" #myModal>...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the service instead creating an instance of it. Make these changes to the code :

```
import {NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
...
...
@ViewChild('myModal') div:any;

constructor(private modalService: NgbModal )

ngAfterViewInit() {
     // make sure you get the instance of the child.
     this.modalService.open(this.div);  
}
```